# Generator not working in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, generator, rails-engines

I have a problem when creating a generator inside a gem. When I run `rails g` the generator is shown:

```
Supportator:
  supportator:initializer
```

But when I run the generator with `rails generate supportator:initializer` the following error occurs:

```
Could not find generator supportator:initializer.
```

This is the code of the generator:

```
require 'rails/generators'

module Supportator
  class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

    def create_initializer_file
      copy_file '_browser_validator.html.haml', 'app/views/_browser_validator.html.haml'
      copy_file 'en_supportator.yml' , 'config/locales/en_supportator.yml'
      copy_file 'es_supportator.yml' , 'config/locales/es_supportator.yml'
    end

  end
end
```

This is the code of the engine:

```
module Supportator
  require 'rails'
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you create the generator in `lib/generators/` directory?

Comment: The generator is located in `lib/generators/supportator/supportator_generator.rb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
lib/generators/supportator/supportator_generator.rb
```

to

```
lib/generators/supportator/initializer_generator.rb
```

Your class name is `InitializerGenerator` so file name should be `initializer_generator.rb`.
Otherwise, rails would not be able to find it.

In your case with `rails g supportator:initializer`, rails would look for a generator file `initializer_generator.rb` in `lib/generators/supportator` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the directory and the name of the file. To the following generator:

```
require 'rails/generators'

module Supportator
  module Generators
      class InstallGenerator < ::Rails::Generators::Base
        source_root File.expand_path("../../../templates", __FILE__)

        def create_initializer_file
          copy_file '_browser_validator.html.haml', 'app/views/_browser_validator.html.haml'
          copy_file 'en_supportator.yml' , 'config/locales/en_supportator.yml'
          copy_file 'es_supportator.yml' , 'config/locales/es_supportator.yml'
        end

      end
  end
end
```

The directory and the file name should be:

```
/lib
  /generators
    /supportator
      /install
        /install_generator.rb
```

Comment: Your Original Question and Answer posted here doesn't match. There is no `module Generators` or `class InstallGenerator` in the question. All my effort answering the question is in vain as now you reverted my accepted answer?